# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [16,2278,4] vs. [16,3000,4]

Tags: deep-learning

I'm running RFB-Net-mobile model with python Keras. And I face the error when i start training. i guess that [16,3000,4] 16 is batch_size,3000 is the Output Shape of "predictions (Concatenate)".i try to change the batch_size but this way don't work.It's very helpful if anyone could give me some advice.thanks.

error:
Warning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
"Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
Epoch 1/50
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1278, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1263, in _run_fn
options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1350, in _call_tf_sessionrun
run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [16,2278,4] vs. [16,3000,4]
[[Node: loss/predictions_loss/sub_1 = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/AddN_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](loss/predictions_loss/strided_slice_4, loss/predictions_loss/strided_slice_5)]]
[[Node: loss/mul/_3821 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_34356_loss/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:/dl/final-vision-mbV3-SSD-RFB-SE-essay-keras_add_extra_layer_use_mbv3/train.py", line 123, in 
initial_epoch=Init_epoch)
File "D:\Anaconda\envs\czh-tfkeras\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Anaconda\envs\czh-tfkeras\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2224, in fit_generator
class_weight=class_weight)
File "D:\Anaconda\envs\czh-tfkeras\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1883, in train_on_batch
outputs = self.train_function(ins)
File "D:\Anaconda\envs\czh-tfkeras\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2478, in **call**
**self.session_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 877, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1100, in _run
feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1272, in _do_run
run_metadata)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1291, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [16,2278,4] vs. [16,3000,4]
[[Node: loss/predictions_loss/sub_1 = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/AddN_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](loss/predictions_loss/strided_slice_4, loss/predictions_loss/strided_slice_5)]]
[[Node: loss/mul/_3821 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_34356_loss/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Caused by op 'loss/predictions_loss/sub_1', defined at:
File "e:/dl/final-vision-mbV3-SSD-RFB-SE-essay-keras_add_extra_layer_use_mbv3/train.py", line 110, in 
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate_base),loss=MultiboxLoss(NUM_CLASSES, neg_pos_ratio=3.0).compute_loss)
File "D:\Anaconda\envs\czh-tfkeras\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 830, in compile
sample_weight, mask)
File "D:\Anaconda\envs\czh-tfkeras\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 429, in weighted
score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
File "e:\dl\final-vision-mbV3-SSD-RFB-SE-essay-keras_add_extra_layer_use_mbv3\nets\ssd_training.py", line 49, in compute_loss
y_pred[:, :, :4])
File "e:\dl\final-vision-mbV3-SSD-RFB-SE-essay-keras_add_extra_layer_use_mbv3\nets\ssd_training.py", line 24, in _l1_smooth_loss
sq_loss = 0.5 * (y_true - y_pred)**2
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line
850, in binary_op_wrapper
return func(x, y, name=name)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 8769, in sub
"Sub", x=x, y=y, name=name)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3155, in create_op
op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1717, in **init**
self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [16,2278,4] vs. [16,3000,4]
[[Node: loss/predictions_loss/sub_1 = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training/Adam/gradients/AddN_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](loss/predictions_loss/strided_slice_4, loss/predictions_loss/strided_slice_5)]]
[[Node: loss/mul/_3821 = _Recv[client_termina
PU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/de
loss/mul", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localho

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
   log_dir = "logs/"
   annotation_path = '2007_train.txt'
   NUM_CLASSES = 21
   input_shape = [300, 300, 3]
   anchors_size = [30,60,111,162,213,264,315]
   priors = get_anchors((input_shape[0], input_shape[1]), anchors_size)
   bbox_util = BBoxUtility(NUM_CLASSES, priors)

    model = SSD300(input_shape, NUM_CLASSES, anchors_size)
    model_path = 'model_data/mobilenet_v3_large_224_1.0_float_no_top.h5'
    # model.load_weights(model_path, by_name=True, skip_mismatch=True)

    logging = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(log_dir + 'ep{epoch:03d}-loss{loss:.3f}-val_loss{val_loss:.3f}.h5',
        monitor='val_loss', save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=False, period=1)
    reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=3, verbose=1)
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=10, verbose=1)

    val_split = 0.1
    with open(annotation_path) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    np.random.seed(10101)
    np.random.shuffle(lines)
    np.random.seed(None)
    num_val = int(len(lines)*val_split)
    num_train = len(lines) - num_val
    
    for i in range(80):
        model.layers[i].trainable = False
    if True:
        Init_epoch = 0
        Freeze_epoch = 50
        BATCH_SIZE = 16
        learning_rate_base = 5e-4

        gen = Generator(bbox_util, BATCH_SIZE, lines[:num_train], lines[num_train:],
                        (input_shape[0], input_shape[1]),NUM_CLASSES)

        model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate_base),loss=MultiboxLoss(NUM_CLASSES, neg_pos_ratio=3.0).compute_loss)
        model.fit_generator(gen.generate(True), 
                steps_per_epoch=num_train//BATCH_SIZE,
                validation_data=gen.generate(False),
                validation_steps=num_val//BATCH_SIZE,
                epochs=Freeze_epoch, 
                initial_epoch=Init_epoch,
                callbacks=[logging, checkpoint, reduce_lr, early_stopping])

    for i in range(80):
        model.layers[i].trainable = True
    if True:
        Freeze_epoch = 50
        Epoch = 100
        BATCH_SIZE = 8
        learning_rate_base = 1e-4
        
        gen = Generator(bbox_util, BATCH_SIZE, lines[:num_train], lines[num_train:],
                        (input_shape[0], input_shape[1]),NUM_CLASSES)

        model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate_base),loss=MultiboxLoss(NUM_CLASSES, neg_pos_ratio=3.0).compute_loss)
        model.fit_generator(gen.generate(True), 
                steps_per_epoch=num_train//BATCH_SIZE,
                validation_data=gen.generate(False),
                validation_steps=num_val//BATCH_SIZE,
                epochs=Epoch, 
                initial_epoch=Freeze_epoch,
                callbacks=[logging, checkpoint, reduce_lr, early_stopping])
```

[resulting image][1]

part of model.summary() is here
'''

---

mbox_loc (Concatenate)          (None, 12000)        0           norm_mbox_loc_flat[0][0]
fc7_mbox_loc_flat[0][0]
conv6_2_mbox_loc_flat[0][0]
conv7_2_mbox_loc_flat[0][0]
conv8_2_mbox_loc_flat[0][0]
conv9_2_mbox_loc_flat[0][0]

---

mbox_conf_logits (Reshape)      (None, 3000, 21)     0           mbox_conf[0][0]

---

norm_mbox_priorbox (PriorBox)   (None, 2166, 8)      0           activation_46[0][0]

---

fc7_mbox_priorbox (PriorBox)    (None, 600, 8)       0           multiply_20[0][0]

---

conv6_2_mbox_priorbox (PriorBox (None, 150, 8)       0           activation_62[0][0]

---

conv7_2_mbox_priorbox (PriorBox (None, 54, 8)        0           activation_65[0][0]

---

conv8_2_mbox_priorbox (PriorBox (None, 24, 8)        0           activation_68[0][0]

---

conv9_2_mbox_priorbox (PriorBox (None, 6, 8)         0           activation_71[0][0]

---

mbox_loc_final (Reshape)        (None, 3000, 4)      0           mbox_loc[0][0]

---

mbox_conf_final (Activation)    (None, 3000, 21)     0           mbox_conf_logits[0][0]

---

mbox_priorbox (Concatenate)     (None, 3000, 8)      0           norm_mbox_priorbox[0][0]
fc7_mbox_priorbox[0][0]
conv6_2_mbox_priorbox[0][0]
conv7_2_mbox_priorbox[0][0]
conv8_2_mbox_priorbox[0][0]
conv9_2_mbox_priorbox[0][0]

---

## predictions (Concatenate)       (None, 3000, 33)     0           mbox_loc_final[0][0]
mbox_conf_final[0][0]
mbox_priorbox[0][0]

Total params: 5,065,384
Trainable params: 5,019,996
Non-trainable params: 45,388

---

'''
[part of resulting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91Oco.jpg)

Comment: To better understand your problem give a command keras.utils.plot_model(model,'networkstructure.png',show_dtype=True) and show the resulting image here. Because you have errors give the command somewhere before the problem occurs in the code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Formatting question is necessary. Here is the link to learn about it  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @Experience_In_AI   i followed your instruction,but another error occurred

Comment: @forDL so you are not able to use keras.utils.plot_model... How about model.summary() ... what does it produces?

Comment: @Experience_In_AI thanks for your help! the error is here
'''
TypeError: plot_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'show_dtype'
'''
if without this keyword argument,the resulting image will show
I have uploaded the resulting image in the answer

Comment: @forDL thanks for the resulting_image, but resolution is not high enough to read. Hence please add a screenshot of the last part of the network only here (to be able to read the text and parameters), what does it look like?

Comment: @Experience_In_AI I have uploaded part of the resulting image and part of model.summary() in the answer

Comment: @Experience_In_AI If it's convenient for you,you can open this website to check the resulting image and the model summary
'''
https://github.com/getr1ch/tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError-Incompatible-shapes-16-2278-4-vs.-  
'''

Comment: You have a lot of code, not time to go through but happy to help in general level. Thus, what is input size of your model? If (1,19,19,672), then if you write probeoutput=model(tf.random.uniform((1,19,19,672))) ... if the input size is no that, feed in the correct format and .. then what is probeoutput.shape ? Does it work succesfully?

Comment: @Experience_In_AI  sorry,i'm new at deeplearning.You mean i should add this line
'''
probeoutput=model(tf.random.uniform((1,19,19,672)))
'''
to my code?but my input size of my model is (16, 300,300,3)->(batch size =16, channels =3)
so i should add this ↓ code and print (probeoutput) ?
'''
probeoutput=model(tf.random.uniform((16,300,300,3)))
''"
(1,19,19,672) 19,19,672 is the shape of first effective feature layer(there are 6) in mobilenetv3-ssd net
by the way            (1,19,19,672)
                               ↑
                               this number refers to batch_size?

Comment: @Experience_In_AI the probeoutput.shape is (16, 3000, 33), dtype=float32
I’m not sure if I got that.here is the code
'''
if __name__ == "__main__":
    NUM_CLASSES = 21
    input_shape = (300, 300, 3) 
    model = SSD300(input_shape, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
    probeoutput=model(tf.random.uniform((16,300,300,3))) 
    print(probeoutput)
'''